# How can I tell what language a file is written in?

Tags: file-extension, decompiler

I've been trying to find, for a long time, what language this file is written in so that I can decompile it. I have tried to decompile as .luac, .class and also tried to open it as .jar and .rar and .zip.

Although the file extension is .car I have never seen this extension before and there certainly aren't any openers for it on the internet. I have even gone to the point of finding a .car opener, but it wasn't for my .car.

So, I suspect it has just been renamed.

Can anyone tell me what language it is coded in?

I don't know if I'm allowed to post files here, as I have only just joined, but here is a Dropbox link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6jd62lfywoskqi/code.car?dl=1

Any help would be appreciated. This is the first line in Notepad++:

rac   T  D      `     constants.lu       œÂ     tools.stashsaver.lu    à     scenes.sellitems.lu    ˆî     scenes.draw.lu     ¼    gui.menu.lu    6    scenes.missions.lu     ˆP

Comment: From the file contents, it is some kind of archive file, along the lines of a `tar` (but not a tar).  A quick Google for "archive file car" tells me that there a "compressed archive" file type that conventionally uses extension ".car".  I'd never heard of it before.

Comment: http://filext.com/file-extension/CAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick dump of the file leads to several URLs referencing:

```
http://www.coronalabs.com/
```

So based on this I'd say the file was created with the SDK they offer.

https://coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/

> Corona lets developers use integrated Lua, layered on top of
>   C++/OpenGL, to build graphic applications. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_%28software%29

Comment: Thanks for this. Turns out it was a resource file compiled by Corona. It contained .lu files which were then easy to decompile. Thanks for the help!